# How to develop a secure database migration software?

Tags: java, database

I want to develop a secure database migration software. My objective is the software must be able to migrate data from an Oracle 11g database to a MySQL database. I know Java and would like to do in that.

Comment: Way too vague of question.  Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: Absolutely. I want to know how to develop a migration software with Java?

Comment: Stackoverflow is aimed more at specific questions than "teach me about an entire branch of programming!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to develop an application to read Oracle database structure, identifying tables, views, constraints, etc and their structures (types, null-ability, lengths, etc) translating that to your target database platform. First phase should be DDL migration.

After that, you must read all source data and import it to target database. Consider scenarios  like keeping source records IDs. Second phase should be DML migration.

Notice not all database objects are simple to migrate. For instance, stored procedures could contains code targeting specifically that Oracle database and should be translated manually.

Comment: Thanks, I have got some idea!